# cppdepend. issues? release notes? community? support?

Tags: c++, code-analysis, static-analysis, cppdepend

I've **discovered a cppdepend** tool for analyzing huge project(s). But as I see it has some issues.

For example, the main and critical (for me) is that some dependencies, which I see right in code by myself, cppdepends doesn't see and tells that elements are independent with each other. As I see the problem is near templates and macros in C++ code.

So I try to find a way to avoid this problem, maybe I can help cppdepend to see this dependencies. Googling doesn't help me. I didn't found any community/forums/groups/blogs where developers (including from cppdepend team) can discuss this tool to find answers for their questions. The last blogs, issue reports are dating from **2010**.

Moreover, official site **doesn't contain any release notes**, bugs reports, "what's new" list.

Unbelievable, that all references about so powerfull tool, which by the way has docs, videos, lessons and so on, are only in posts like that:

> "What tool would you recomend?"
>
> "Try cppdepend."

Comment: c++ code is super difficult to parse. Therefore it doesn't surprise that you see some problems. If you can, report it to developers.

Comment: From http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0064/  it appears that cppdepend is using Doxygen to parse the C++ code. Doxygen is known to have troubles collecting accurate information about C++ code, because it has a hueristic parser for C++, not a full blown language front end.  What this means is any "dependency" it might or might not find, might or might not be real, and there's no way to fix it short of replacing the front end.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Ira Baxter , CppDepend 2.X use Doxygen , and some dependencies could not be found , the Version 3 use Clang instead of Doxygen, please contact us at support@cppdepend.com   to try CppDepend 3 Beta;

And for any other problems concerning CppDepend 2.X please contact us at support@cppdepend.com, we will try to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: ОК. I send to support@cppdepend.com a letter with topic "Issue. Cannot found dependency through getter."<br/><br/>

          <code>void A::fooA()
          {
               GetB().fooB();
          }</code><br/>

Here we can see, that **fooA is really called method fooB**.

And analyzer shows me that **fooA() does not depend on fooB()**.
It is stange but cppdepend shows dependency projectA on projectB.

And if I write fooA like this:
          void fooA()
          {
               b_.fooB();
          }

Then it will be ok.